# Meteor parameters and where they come from

Tags: meteor

I have a question where all the parameters for the meteor functions are coming from? Things like postAttribues, id, postId, limit, etc, etc...

```
Meteor.publish('newPosts', function(limit) {
  return Posts.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: limit});
});
Meteor.publish('singlePost', function(id) {
  return id && Posts.find(id);
});
//related to post
Meteor.publish('comments', function(postId) {
  return Comments.find({postId: postId});
});
```

Are they signaled from Mongo DB? It's fine and dandy to memorize these things, but it would be nice to know where these parameters are coming from and what parameters are usually available to me.

I never used any frameworks before, so this may be why I'm confused. I worked exclusively with Javascript before jumping on Meteor.

I also have the same question about Iron Router: When creating a route, we can set a route with a specific Id with `/randomName/:_id` and the unique code that's responsible for associating the ":_Id" with the actual page is `this.params._id`. Why and how does the back end associate these things?

I would appreciate any help to help me understand this better.

Comment: "Why and how does the back end associate these things?" is way too broad as it requires a large analysis of the code to provide a decent answer. As for your first question, well... They just come from the way Meteor defines its API, I don't really know what could properly answer that.

Answer (score 1):

A meteor `find()` query follows the syntax `find({query}, {options})` defined here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find where the `options` parameter is an object containing `sort, limit, etc..`.  These options look similar to some Mongo operators such as `.sort()` and `.limit()` but are defined

The parameters `limit` and `sort` are part of the `options` parameter.  It would be useful to review the documentation for Meteor found here: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/

The parameter `postId` comes from the way you have defined your objects in your DB.  This field is part of your `query` parameter which specifies what exactly to find in the DB.  So by specifying a `postId:`, Meteor will look through your `Comments` collection for any containing the `postId` that you pass.  When you pass a string as the query parameter, it is expected that that string is an _id in your collection.

For the parameters being passed into the publication itself see docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe . It comes from the subscription. Basically, you can pass. Parameters between the client and the server this way. To make your publication more robust, you can add parameters as you wish so that the client can specify which 'id' or 'limit' that they want.

As for your iron:router question, I am not sure exactly what you are asking about how the backend associates parameters and the page itself.  Perhaps you could be more specific and update your question accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

I read over the MongoDB operators beforehand, so I know most of the things in terms of Mongo DB.

However, my question is this...in this code:

`Meteor.publish('newPosts', function(limit) {
  return Posts.find({}, {sort: {submitted: -1}, limit: limit});
});`

Specifically here:

`Meteor.publish('newPosts', function(limit)`
the function has a "limit" parameter. Where does this limit come from? I know in the find cursor, we are looking through all documents, sorting submitted from decreasing order and setting limit to the "limit" parameter passed in to the function.

Comment: See http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe .  It comes from the subscription.

Comment: Basically,  you can pass. Parameters between the client and the server this way.   To make your publication more robust, you can add parameters as you wish so that the client can specify which 'id' or 'limit' that they want